# How to have nested configurations in config json file and read it using bit?

Tags: bit-framework

so far I've seen some sample code in which some configuration is inserted in a file named `environment.json` like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Default",

    "AppInfo": {
          "Name": "blahblah",
          "Version": "1"
    },
    "Configs": [
      {
        "Key": "someconfiguration",
        "Value": "some value"
      },
      {
        "Key": "another configuration ",
        "Value": "blah blah"
      },
    ]
   }
]
```

and then when needed, data can be read from configuration file like this:

```
var value = DefaultAppEnvironmentsProvider.Current
            .GetActiveAppEnvironment()
            .GetConfig<string>("SomeConfiguration");
```

#### The Question is:

what if I want to have some `configuration` whose value is a nested `json list` or `json object`. I want some thing like this:

```
"key": "Address",
"value": {
    "street": "some street name",
    "postal code": "blah blah",
    ...
}
```

how can I read such configurations using [bit](https://docs.bit-framework.com/)?

thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create a class which defines your configuration contract:

```
public class MailServerConfig
{
    public Uri ServerUrl { get; set; }

    public string AnotherConfig { get; set; }
}
```

Then add followings to your environments.json file:

```
,
      {
        "Key": "MailServerConfig",
        "Value": {
          "$type": "SampleApp.Configurations.MailServerConfig, SampleApp",
          "ServerUrl": "https://google.com/",
          "AnotherConfig": "!"
        }
      }
```

In your controllers (Or wherever you want to read your configs), inject AppEnv

```
public AppEnvironment AppEnv { get; set; }
```

Then read your config as below:

```
MailServerConfig mailServerConfig = AppEnv.GetConfig<MailServerConfig>("MailServerConfig");
```

Note that in environments.json, $type is mandatory, and it should be the first line of your nested json object.